# print integer in a string javascript

Tags: javascript, string, console.log

Is it possible to print a string by referencing a variable similar to C's printf function? I do not want to concatenate strings with '+' operator.

for example:

```
console.log("What the difference in %i - %i ?", 7, 2);
```

should output:

```
What the difference in 7-2 ?
```

Comment: Have you tried it? Works just fine in Chrome.

Comment: I have, but it doesn't appear to work in my brackets IDE